# Comparando valores de colunas em linhas de pandas dataframe

Tags: mysql, sql, python, dataframe

Boa tarde. Estou comparando dois dada frames,o data frame 1 possui uma consulta sql e o data frame 2 uma consulta mysql quero comparar os dois. Quando o registro do DF 1 não estiver no DF 2 quero guardar o resultado em outro data frame vazio, para depois carregar os dados desse data frame vazio na minha tabela no mysql, assim podendo automatizar um processo.

> DF1 = Função para conexão com banco sql server e dataframe 1
>
> DF2 = Função para conexão com banco Mysql e dataframe 2

```
import pymysql.cursors
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# Função para trazer os dados do Sql e jogar em um dataframe
def get_vendas_sqlserver():
    #Conexão com SQL Server
    connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SQLServer")  #autocommit=True
    try:
        # Conteúdo do data frame 1
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dw.dbo.vW_Vendateste123",connection,index_col=None,coerce_float=True, parse_dates= 'DataBaseContrato') 
        return df      
    finally:
        connection.close()


# Função para trazer os dados do mysql e jogar em um dataframe
def get_vendas_mysql():
    #Conexão Mysql
    cnxmysql = pymysql.connect(host='teste',
                                 user='teste',
                                 password='teste',
                                 db='dw')
    try:
        # Conteúdo do data frame 2
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM ft_venda_copy", cnxmysql, index_col=None, coerce_float=True,
                               parse_dates='DataBaseContrato')
        return df
    finally:
        cnxmysql.close()

def compara_valores():
    cnx = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://teste:teste@teste/dw')
    df1 = get_vendas_sqlserver()
    df2 = get_vendas_mysql()
    #criando um dataframe vazio para guardar o resultado
    df_result = pd.DataFrame()
    print('df1: ',df1,' ', 'df2: ',df2, sep='\n')



    # o metodo iterrows retorna um tuple com o indice 
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    # verifica se este registro existe no DF do MySQL
        if row["IdContrato"] in df2["IdContrato"]:
            print("Contrato {0} encontrada no Mysql".format(row["Idcontrato"]))       
        else:
            print("Contrato {0} nao encontrada no Mysql".format(row["IdContrato"]))

        df_result.to_sql(con=cnx, name='ft_venda_copy', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

> Quando vou verificar o data frame Result ele me retorna vazio

```
# adiciona o registro em um novo DF que vai ser usado para gravar no banco
df_result.append(row)
print(df_result)


df1:
      IdUnidade  IdContrato  IdProspect TipoContrato  ... 
0           276      9607.0         NaN          PCV  ...                 
1           328      8391.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
2           362     10233.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
3           309     10548.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
4           237      8849.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
5           308      8116.0         NaN          PCV  ...            0 

[6355 rows x 34 columns]


df2:
      IdUnidade  IdContrato  IdProspect TipoContrato  ... 
0           276      9607.0         NaN          PCV  ...                 
1           328      8391.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
2           362     10233.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
3           309     10548.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
4           237      8849.0         NaN          PCV  ...            
5           308      8116.0         NaN          PCV  ...            0 

[6355 rows x 34 columns]
```

Comment: Voce editou a pergunta, adicionou o comando que sugeri nos comentarios da minha resposta, mas note que eu comentei "Execute e reproduza o resultado na sua questao.", cadê o resultado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria que vc mostrasse o conteudo dos dataframes, ficou dificil entender o contexto, então vou tentar dar um exemplo baseado no que entendi da sua pergunta, vou criar 1 dataframe `df1` e depois copia-lo para um segundo `df2` e então alterar o dado da primeira coluna da segunda linha do `df1`, ou seja, o primeiro dataframe `df1` conterá uma linha (a segunda) que não estará contida no segundo `df2`, então 'navego' nas linhas do `df1` verificando se o valor da primeira coluna de cada linha está contida na mesma coluna do `df2`, caso não esteja, salvo essa(s) linha(s) em uma lista e, finalmente a coverto para um dataframe

> Depois de 'Teracentos' comentários e edições na pergunta, editei o exemplo para adaptar ao contexto.

```
import pandas as pd

a1 = [['276', '9607.0','NaN','PCV'], 
      ['328', '8391.0','NaN','PCV'], 
      ['362', '10233.0','NaN','PCV']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a1, columns=['IdUnidade','IdContrato','IdProspect','TipoContrato'])
df2 = df1.copy()

# Incluindo uma nova linha em df1
df1.loc[len(df1)] = ['999', '9999.9','999','PCV']

# Aturalizando df2 em função de df1...
old_df2 = df2.copy()
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['IdContrato'] not in list(df2['IdContrato']):
        df2.loc[len(df2)] = list(row)

# Apresentando os resultados
print('','df1:', df1,'','df2 original:',old_df2,'','Novo df2:',df2,sep='\n')
```

Saida:

```
df1:
  IdUnidade IdContrato IdProspect TipoContrato
0       276     9607.0        NaN          PCV
1       328     8391.0        NaN          PCV
2       362    10233.0        NaN          PCV
3       999     9999.9        999          PCV

df2 original:
  IdUnidade IdContrato IdProspect TipoContrato
0       276     9607.0        NaN          PCV
1       328     8391.0        NaN          PCV
2       362    10233.0        NaN          PCV

Novo df2:
  IdUnidade IdContrato IdProspect TipoContrato
0       276     9607.0        NaN          PCV
1       328     8391.0        NaN          PCV
2       362    10233.0        NaN          PCV
3       999     9999.9        999          PCV
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/dataframe-compare?language=python3&folderId=)

Comment: Sidon adicionei o conteúdo dos data frame no caso seriam duas tabela uma sql e outra my sql, aplicaria da mesma forma do seu exemplo ??

Comment: Se meu exemplo esta de acordo com sua necessidade, vai se aplicar. Onde vc adicionou os conteudos dos 2 DFs? Além da falta disso, parece que sua questão esta mal formatada ou faltando mais coisas, o ultimo bloco de codigo que vc apresenta, não deveria esta dentro do `for index, row...` do bloco de codigo anterior?

Comment: Sidon, dei uma reformulada na pergunta e adicionei as parte que faltavam no código, e obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Ainda não apresentou os `dfs` e a formatacao ainda parece errada.  para apresentar os dfs, faca assim: Em `def compara_valores()`, crie uma linha naquele espaço vago, no meio do bloco de codigo, com o seguinte comando: `print('df1:',df1,' ', 'df2:',df2, sep='\n')`. Execute e reproduza o resultado na sua questao.

Comment: Editei a perguntou com o que você pediu

Comment: Não, vc não fez o que eu sugeri, veja nos comentários da sua pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei o resultado resumido dos data frames repare que os dois tem os mesmo dados, a intenção é carregar os dados no df 2 quando tiver novos dados no df 1

Comment: Ok, estou editando minha resposta para adaptar ao seu contexto, depoi eu mando o numero da minha conta para o seu patrão fazer o depósito, certo? :-)

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou a entender